# Twilio TaskRouter - Accepting a reservation from the JS client

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I am using the Taskrouter js library, more specifically the worker.js.

```
  this.worker.on("reservation.created", (reservation) => {
      reservation.accept()
  });
```

However, I am getting an error saying that

> accept() is not a function

According to the documentation here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-js

> This will accept the reservation for the worker.
>
> Note: This will NOT perform any telephony. If the task was enqueued
>   using the Enqueue TwiML verb, utilize
>   reservation.dequeue(#reservation-dequeue) to perform telephony and
>   dequeue the call.

```
reservation.accept(
    function(error, reservation) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error.code);
            console.log(error.message);
            return;
        }
        console.log("reservation accepted");
        for (var property in reservation) {
            console.log(property+" : "+reservation[property]);
        }
    }
);
```

So we I am confused as reservation has no function  **accept()**, but according to the documentation it does... So how do I accept a reservation from js?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `this.worker.on`?

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-js#example_6

```
worker.on("reservation.created", function(reservation) {
    console.log(reservation.task.attributes)      // {foo: 'bar', baz: 'bang' }
    console.log(reservation.task.priority)        // 1
    console.log(reservation.task.age)             // 300
    console.log(reservation.task.sid)             // WTxxx
    console.log(reservation.sid)                  // WRxxx
});
```

Comment: It is that way because there is taskrouter service wrapping the worker instantiation. What turned out to be the issue was that we were loading an older version of the library SMH all good now 